# Why does this LINQ query fail to work?

Tags: c#, linq, async-await, entity-framework-core

I am running into a problem that I like to understand why it is happening. Some help would be appreciated.

I am using entity framework core and this is the query I have in my code:

```
var user = await _db.User
      .Where(x => x.Email == username & x.Suspended == null)
      .Select(x => new
      {
           x.UserId,
           x.Password,
           x.Salt,
           Role = x.Role.Name
      })
      .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

[image]

This query does not select the user but it doesn't throw any error ether. If I remove "x.Suspended" from Where clause than it will return the user.
The "Suspended" is a table that is related to the user table by the user ID. The user ID is PKs in both tables, so the relation is 1 to 1.
I think this query does not return the user because the x.Suspended is null. Can some one help me understand why this is happening and what I can do to make it work.

UPDATE:
Ok, I used SQL server profiler and this is the converted sql by entity framework:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [x.Suspended].[UserId], [x.Suspended].[RCD], [x.Suspended].[Reason], [x].[UserId], [x].[Password], [x].[Salt], [x.Role].[Name]
FROM [User] AS [x]
INNER JOIN [Role] AS [x.Role] ON [x].[RoleId] = [x.Role].[RoleId]
INNER JOIN [Suspended] AS [x.Suspended] ON [x].[UserId] = [x.Suspended].[UserId]
WHERE [x].[Email] = @__username_0',N'@__username_0 varchar(80)',@__username_0='some-username'
```

the problem here is that all one-to-one relations are converted to INNER JOINs. How can I handle this problem? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE 2:
I am starting to think that this is a bug in EF Core. For example when I have this:

```
var user = await _db.User
      .Include(x => x.Role)
      .Include(x => x.Suspended)
      .Where(x => x.Email == username)
      .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Under profiler the sql output is this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(2) [x].[UserId], [x].[Email], [x].[FirstName], [x].[LastName], [x].[Password], [x].[Phone], [x].[RCD], [x].[RoleId], [x].[Salt], [s].[UserId], [s].[RCD], [s].[Reason], [r].[RoleId], [r].[Name]
FROM [User] AS [x]
LEFT JOIN [Suspended] AS [s] ON [s].[UserId] = [x].[UserId]
INNER JOIN [Role] AS [r] ON [x].[RoleId] = [r].[RoleId]
WHERE [x].[Email] = @__username_0',N'@__username_0 varchar(80)',@__username_0='user-email'
```

Clearly the "Suspended" table is left join not inner. But when I have this:

```
 var user1 = await _db.User
       .Include(x => x.Role)
       .Include(x => x.Suspended)
       .Where(x => x.Email == username & x.Suspended == null)
       .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

The sql under the sql profiler is:

```
SELECT [x].[UserId], [x].[Email], [x].[FirstName], [x].[LastName], [x].[Password], [x].[Phone], [x].[RCD], [x].[RoleId], [x].[Salt], [x.Suspended].[UserId], [x.Suspended].[RCD], [x.Suspended].[Reason], [s].[UserId], [s].[RCD], [s].[Reason], [r].[RoleId], [r].[Name]
FROM [User] AS [x]
INNER JOIN [Suspended] AS [x.Suspended] ON [x].[UserId] = [x.Suspended].[UserId]
LEFT JOIN [Suspended] AS [s] ON [s].[UserId] = [x].[UserId]
INNER JOIN [Role] AS [r] ON [x].[RoleId] = [r].[RoleId]
```

what a mess :-D how the hell do we have "Suspended" table joined twice, INNER and LEFT? And where is the WHERE clause?

### All I want is this in LINQ to work:

```
SELECT U.[UserId], U.[Password], U.[Salt], R.[Name] AS [Role]
FROM [ag].[dbo].[User] AS U
INNER JOIN [ag].[dbo].[Role] AS R ON U.[RoleId] = R.[RoleId]
LEFT JOIN [ag].[dbo].[Suspended] AS S ON U.[UserId] = S.[UserId]
WHERE U.[Email] = 'john.smith@gmail.com' AND S.[UserId] IS NULL
```

Comment: But that `INNER JOIN` will do exactly what you need - remove rows with `null` `Suspended`. The only thing that surprises me is `INNER JOIN` on `Role` table, which I believe is caused by `x.Role.Name` in `Select` clause. Try `Role = x.Role == null ? null : x.Role.Name`, but I'm not sure if that will help.

Comment: The relation between user and suspended is 1..0-1 not 1:1

Comment: Thanks Robert, well the Idea here is that if a user has been suspended than a record should be in "Suspended" table with a reason and date. This query is for authentication and before the user is authenticated and give a token (jwt) I need to make sure that the user is not suspended. INNER join is not helping here at all. I do understand why they design it this way.

Comment: The Role is a table its self to like Suspended with one-to-one relationship with the user. The only difference is that user record has RoleId column. It seems the EF converts all one-to-one relations to inner joins.

Comment: Yes, because all 1:1 relationships are essentially an inner join.

Comment: If a user that is not suspended has a record in the suspended table, then the relationship is 1:1.  If not, then it is 1:0-1.  If you have it set up as 1:0-1 then suspended is a collection, if it's 1:1 then it is not.  It probably should be set up as 1:0..1, and the role table should be set up as 1:* so that each user can have many roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right on this, it is a bug and will be fixed in the future EF core releases. Here is the link to the issue on **[github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6844)**.

Answer (score 0):

You should use &&

```
var user = await _db.User
      .Where(x => x.Email == username && x.Suspended != null)
      .Select(x => new
      {
           x.UserId,
           x.Password,
           x.Salt,
           Role = x.Role.Name
      })
      .SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Tried that too, doesn't help.

Comment: Hmm, is Suspended null? it works if it is not null but doesn't if it is null.

Comment: Well, x.Suspended is a table (an object by its own). See the schema of the db I posted. It is not a Boolean value.

Comment: @Arman probably need to check your suspended.userid and userid from the main table

Comment: @Sajeetharan if the user suspended than there should be a record in Suspended table for the user. This particular user is not suspended so there is no record in that table so x.Suspended is null in this case. I probably need to look at the profiler and see what is the sql that is send to the server.

Comment: I found the cause but don't know how to make it work. Simply when EF converts the linq to sql it uses inner join not left in this case.

Comment: `Where(x => x.Email == username && !x.Suspended.Any())`

Comment: @Robert, first I thought what a moron I am when I saw your comment but than I realized that I can't use .Any() since x.Suspended is not a collection.